# Mixing global and frame navigation in nativescript-vue doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I tried to use playground on two different phones but it didn't work on any of them so I try to share my code here.

I initialize Vue like this in my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import Main from './components/Main.vue';
import store from './store';

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h('frame', [h(store.state.is_logged_in ? Main : Login)]),
}).$start();
```

My Login.vue looks like this:

```
<template>
  <page actionBarHidden="true">
    <ScrollView orientation="vertical">
      <GridLayout rows="2*,auto,3*" height="100%">
...
      </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </page>
</template>

<script>
import Main from './Main.vue';
  export default {
    name: 'Login',
    methods: {
      login() {
        this.$navigateTo(Main);
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

And my Main.vue looks like this:

```
<template>
  <Page actionBarHidden="true">
    <StackLayout height="100%">
      <GridLayout height="7%" id="topBar" columns="*,*,*">
...
      </GridLayout>
      <StackLayout height="75%">
        <frame id="content">
          <home />
        </frame>
      </StackLayout>
      <navBar height="23%" />
    </stacklayout>
  </page>
</template>

<script>
  import navBar from './navBar.vue';
  import home from './home.vue';
  export default {
    name: 'Main',
    components: {navBar, home},
  };
</script>
```

home.vue looks like this:

```
<template>
  <page actionBarHidden="true">
    <ScrollView>
...
    </ScrollView>
  </page>
</template>
```

And in my navBar.vue I navigate like this:

```
this.$navigateTo(page, {
  frame: 'content',
  props: props,
});
```

If the user is already logged in and thus Main.vue is the first component to get loaded in the root frame, all the navigations work fine. But if The user is not logged in. They get navigated to the Main page after login, but then when I navigate using the navbar as seen above the UI doesn't change at all but in my logs I see that the navigation is actually being made and the correct new page is actually being rendered because I get a lot of `AppendChild`, `CreateElement` etc logs. However, I also have some modals beings opened on click of buttons in the home page and some of them actually have internal navigations(within the popup) and they all work just fine. It's only the navigations within the 'content' frame that don't work.

Any idea how I can workaround this bug?

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj I said in the beginning of my question that I tried and failed to do so. I tried the app on two different phones but it didn't work. if there is a way to preview the playground on the web I would be more than happy to do it. but It's not working on my phones. Maybe it's due to network restrictions, I also tried a VPN tho. But it's not working.

Comment: You could try a Github repo.

Comment: @Manoj I'll try to do that, but that will take some time, but from what I've shared everything sounds like the correct way of handling navigation in nativescript?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, but I can suggest a thing that would probably make your life easier and the app a bit faster after loadtime. Use a tabview to get some sort of HUB-navigation. The important views that you want to have in your navbar would be a lot faster to navigate to. An explanation can be found on: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#bottomnavigation--tabs-navigation

Comment: But I also have some pages that navigate just like this but I don't have them in the bottom navigation bar, So I have 7 pages that share the same top and bottom bar but only 4 of them are included in the bottom navigation bar. how can I handle that?